# Why is this constructor written as it is?

Tags: c++, object, copy-constructor, default-constructor, c-strings

Our professor posted a custom 'String' template file online, and asked us a while ago to fill out the functions below. My question, in order to try and understand this, is why the top three constructors have `Text = NULL;` and below it, `this = source;`, some other form of it. I feel like each should say `Text = the_input_parameter`.

Many thanks, here's the code:

```
class String
{
public:
    // Default constructor
    String()
    {
        Text = NULL;
    }
    String(const String& source)
    {
        Text = NULL;
        // Call the assignment operator to perform deep copy
        *this = source;     
    }
    String(const char* text)
    {
        Text = NULL;
        // Call the assignment operator to perform deep copy

        *this = text;

    }
~String()
    {
        delete[] Text;
    }

    // Assignment operator to perform deep copy
    String& operator = (const char* text)
    {
        // Ddispose of old Text
        delete[] Text;

        // +1 accounts for NULL-terminator
        int trueLength = GetLength(text) + 1;

        // Dynamically allocate characters on heap
        Text = new char[trueLength];

        // Copy all characters from source to Text; +1 accounts for NULL-terminator
        for ( int i = 0; i < trueLength; i++ )
            Text[i] = text[i];

        return *this;
    }

    // Returns a reference to a single character from this String
    char& operator [] (int index) const
    {
        int length = GetLength();

        // Check for valid index
        if ( (index < 0) || (index > length) )
        {
            stringstream error;
            error << "operator[] - index " << index << " is out of bounds (0.." << (length - 1) << ")";
            throw String(error.str().c_str());
        }

        return Text[index];
    }
private:
    // The encapsulated C-string
    char* Text;
};
```

Comment: Do you know the difference between a deep copy and shallow copy? (Also, I hope you learn about ctor initialization lists, delegating constructors, etc.)

Comment: In what unholy pit of pure blasphemy did you dig this code out of???  The constructors are written like that because the person who made this thing doesn't know what they're doing!

Comment: I have to agree with @CrazyEddie: implementing constructors in terms of assignment is ass backwards. I once had to maintain some code that did that. It was torture.

Comment: @JesseGood Deep copy copies the actual value, and shallow just copies the pointer, right? @Crazy What's so wrong about it? They don't seem that horrible to me. There's another one that takes an integer as a parameter, and the only code in the brackets is `Text = new char[size];` With the comment `// Init constructor, allocates this String to hold 'size' characters`

Comment: Well, for one...letting alone the operator= calls, you should be using the initialization list to *initialize* your variables rather than later *assigning* to them.  Frankly, the amount of times you use '=' in constructors should be as close to 0 as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a way to factor out common code into a helper function. In this case, `operator=()` acts as the helper function. Its function is to deallocate the current string (in this case, `NULL`) and perform a deep copy of the right-hand side.

> I feel like each should say `Text = the_input_parameter`.

For `String(const String& source)` this wouldn't compile since `source` isn't the right type.

For `String(const char* text)` this wouldn't be correct since that would just assign the pointer instead of performing a deep copy.

The above assumes you are only showing us a part of the class, and that the actual class defines an appropriate assignment operator and a destructor. If it doesn't, you need a new professor.

Comment: The relationship should be at least inverted such that the assignment operator leverages construction and not the other way around.

Comment: All the functions were originally declared in a header file, and then implemented in a .cpp file. To keep it simpler for myself, I moved them all to the header file. Would that explain it?

As for the assignment operator and destructor, yeah it has them. I didn't think they were relevant for asking purely about constructors. It has people bugging out though, so I'll post em :)

Comment: @DrewDormann: because if you don't initialize the `Text` to `NULL` in the constructor, the `operator=` which follows would call `delete[]` on some random pointer.

Comment: @Nik ^Thank you, that actually provides the most clarification to my original question, haha, although I don't think people were expecting a question so basic :D.

Answer (score 6):

Why you should not implement constructors in terms of assignment:

- It gets pretty nasty in derived classes. Think about it.
- It's difficult to make exception safe.
- It's also inefficient, to boot (requiring default construction then assignment).

So the answer to why it’s done that way in your example code, is possibly that your professor doesn’t know diddly about C++ programming.

Otherwise, it's difficult to say: it just doesn't make any sense at all to do that.

---

Going the other way, however, namely implementing copy assignment in terms of copy construction, is very common and is known as the **copy-and-swap idiom**.

It's simple, exceptions safe and generally efficient, and goes like this:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void swap_with( Foo& other ) throw()
    {
        // No-throwing swap here.
    }

    void operator=( Foo other )
    {
        other.swap_with( *this );
    }
};
```

yup, that's all.

variants include naming the swapper just `swap`, and letting the assignment operator return a reference, and some prefer to pass the argument by reference and then make a copy (using copy construction).

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "implementing constructors in terms of assignment"? Sorry, this is part of why I asked.

Comment: @Reciever80: sure. "implementing constructors in terms of assignment" just means that constructors call the copy assignment operator to the job. instead, the copy assignment operator should call the copy constructor to do the job. the code shown above is a bit more clever. it lets the code that calls the assignment operator, call the copy constructor (for the pass by value argument), but it's the same principle: assignment should be done via construction.

Answer (score 0):

The class manages memory, so destructor releases it, and assignment operator allocates new for new data and releases old one (shoud be in that order).

Then the explanation of initial assignment is clear: you need to initialize the member field to a correct value, as otherwise it will contain garbage (some pointer to somewhere), which code will attempt to use and free.

Though it is not seen from the code, there might be also assignment for `const String&` and type cast operator `operator const char *() const`.